# Adding MySQL requests to JS Code from JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

First and foremost, I want to say how amazing this community is. I've been reading and using this place for a bit now to get answers to a plethora of questions.

I'm currently working on building a student list (never really built a system before) system for our company using Bootstrap 3. I've got the meat of it worked out and have found this awesome JSFiddle by user Mils (many thanks) that does what I need it to in terms of adjusting data dynamically, which would be ideal for what we want.

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/645/

My question is: how can I alter this so that it *pulls* data from a MySQL database I've created, and how do I alter it so that when adding/editing a row, it writes it to the db? I have a students.php page I created that pulls in the information as such:

```
 // Prepare SQL Query
$STM = $db->prepare("SELECT `student_firstname`, `student_lastname`, `student_class`, `year` FROM students ORDER BY student_firstname");
// For executing prepared statement
    $STM->execute();
// Fetch records
$STMrecords = $STM->fetchAll();
foreach($STMrecords as $row)
{
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td><a href='#' id='student-firstname' data-type='text' data-pk=".$row['student_firstname']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['student_lastname']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['student_class']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['year']."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
```

But this doesn't go hand-in-hand with the aforementioned JSFiddle, as it only posts the data on the page.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the `get` request in the JSFiddle to you `php` script. And the `php` script needs to return something on the expected format.

At the end of the fiddle there is a couple of mocks, there you can see how the output from the `php` script should be formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, fredrik. When you say the `get` do you mean the `$http.get` in the JS? Sorry -- I've never done much programming before. And I appreciate the response.

Comment: Yes, the `$http.get`. That is where the group data is fetched.

Comment: Cheers. So if I want to do this for each column, I'd just have to alter the JSFiddle code so that it pulls rows from the db through each `$scope` instance, yes? Ideally, I don't really want the dropdown bits shown in the JSFiddle, but more "editable" data as with the `Name` column. As this is just pulling the rows from the db, could I adjust it so that it posts/updates data on the db tables as well? Thanks again, fredrik